# C programming while loop. Variable compare with variable

Tags: c, variables, while-loop, compare

Can you help me? When I execute this statement, it keeps saying out of upper bound even if it isn't. What is the problem? Thanks.

```
if(number_o_1 <= higher)
    {
        printf("Random number has reached upper bound.\n");

    }
        else
        {
            printf("Number 1: %d\n", number_o_1);
            number_o_up=number_o_1+n_multiple*(x-1);
            while(number_o_up<=higher)
            for(x=2;x<number_r;x++)
            printf("Number %d: %d\n", x,number_o_up);
        }
```

Comment: Since no variable declarations are provided, nobody can say anything meaningful about this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
number_o_1<= higher
```

Sure you want to print that the number has reached the upper bound when it's lesser than or equal to your upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

It is little hard to figure the logic you would like to implement, but please see the example with exact values and comments to hit the else block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 2;
int higher = 100;
int number_o_1 = 10;
int number_r = 4;
int number_o_up = 1;
int n_multiple = 2;

int main()
{
    if(number_o_1 >= higher) // probably want >= here to hit else
    {
        printf("Random number has reached upper bound.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number 1: %d\n", number_o_1);
        number_o_up = number_o_1 + n_multiple * (x-1); // number_o_up = 12
        while(number_o_up <= higher)                   // 12 <= 100
        {
            for(x = 2; x < number_r; x++)              // cond. 2 < 4
            {
                printf("Number %d: %d\n", x, number_o_up);
            }

            number_o_up++; //needs to change higher or number_o_up to get out of while
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sh-4.3$ main
Number 1: 10
Number 2: 12
Number 3: 12
Number 2: 13
Number 3: 13
Number 2: 14
...
Number 3: 100
```